# Python setup.py not adding console_script

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, setuptools

I've looked at the other solutions for this and none of them help.

I installed my package and it doesn't add my entry_point when using --user
After doing pip install --user module 
the entry point is not adding to .local
Does anyone know why it's not getting added to .local/bin?
Developing in python 2.7

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Fix: `conole_scripts` -> `console_scripts`. Missed **s**.

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is a spelling mistake in the `entry_points`, you have `conole_scripts` instead of `console_scripts` (missing the "s" in console).  Was this directly copied and pasted from your code?